# How to spot repetitions inside a paragraph using regex

Tags: regex, grammar, paragraph

For grammar correction, trying to spot if my paragraph has 1 or more repetitions in a sentence.

Tried something like this to no avail:

```
[A-Z][^\\.;]*(This was a)[^\\.;]*
```

For instance, a paragraph like:

> "This was a hot Summer, and seems not be the first. For my next vacation, I plan on going to Las Vegas. This was a weird Summer indeed."

A regex that could spot that my paragraph contains 1 or more repetitions at the beginning of two sentences ("This was a"). What would be the correct regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you there's at least one repetition and of what. It won't tell you where they are:

```
(\b\S.*\b).*[.;:]\s+\K\1
```

- `(\b\S.*\b)` - longest match of something starting with a nonspace that starts and ends on "word" boundary
- `.*` - anything :)
- `[.:;]\s+` - "sentence" terminator followed by at least one space
- `\K` - don't include anything up to here in the match
- `\1` - a repetition of the bracketed portion

https://regex101.com/r/NH7w1R/1/

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I was looking for ...thanks !!

Comment: actually, I guess the `\b\S` could be left out, as it is implied by the subsequent `\s+`

Comment: Correct, it does work without those. Unfortunately, the "\K " is preventing me from implementing it in my c# method, will try to find an alternative to the \K.